# Wrong date format after parsing datetime from server. How to solve?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I get data from server like this - **2022-07-27T15:35:18+03:00**

So I created parser which returns me only hours, minutes, seconds, but I am still facing with problems of `The following FormatException was thrown building StreamBuilder<String?>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<String?, AsyncSnapshot<String?>>#07d8f):`

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<String?>(
                stream: ProviderService.getTime(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  //toLocal() to create the local
                  var localDate = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data ?? '').toLocal();
                  var inputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
                  var inputDate = inputFormat.parse(localDate.toString());
                  var outputFormat = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss');
                  var outputDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
```

**Desired output is: 15:37:18**

Comment: Your input includes time zone information but your inputFormat does not.

Comment: You didn't provide the error message from the `FormatException` itself, and I can't reproduce any exception with the above code using that input string.  Also, why are you using `DateTime.parse`, converting the resulting `DateTime` object to a `String`, and then parsing it again, which is a convoluted no-op?  If your goal is to just discard the timezone information, then should use [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone) instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. I figured out what I'm doing wrong. It's so obvious. I'll post the solution later just in case (suddenly someone
it will be needed)

Comment: Check this for answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236309/how-to-parse-date-2022-08-04t1613510300-correctly-in-dart I found out why my code was wrong