# How to parse date 2022-08-04T16:13:51+03:00 correctly in Dart?

Tags: dart

How to parse time which looks like this - `2022-08-04T16:13:51+03:00`?

As I understood ot is the UNIX time and I tried to convert it something like this:

```
  child: StreamBuilder<String?>(
                stream: ProviderService.getTime(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  var time = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? '').toLocal();
                  String date = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(time);
```

it looks on the screen that it is correctly parsed, but I am still watching this error on stacktrace:

```
The following FormatException was thrown building StreamBuilder<String?>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<String?, AsyncSnapshot<String?>>#76ce0):
Invalid date format

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<String?>
```

Comment: ok, I was so stupid as the stupidest person on the Earth. So it should look like this when I parse it for the first time  `String time = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data?.toString() ??
                          '2022-08-04T16:16:51+03:00')`. This String 2022-08-04T16:16:51+03:00 is required for getting rid of the above error. Now it works perfectly well and nothing  fail

Answer (score 0):

```dart
var time = DateTime.parse(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? '').toLocal();
```

If `snapshot.data` is null, you are passing an empty string into `DateTime.parse`.

To fix this, rather than replacing the empty string with a nonsensical (but parsable) value, [you should be able to use `snapshot.hasData()` to check if the snapshot has any data and if it doesn't display a loading indicator of some sort](https://youtu.be/MkKEWHfy99Y?t=60).